# HTML Convert Text Input into Number and Print to Screen

Tags: html, matrix, datatable

Ok y'all, here's what I got- I need to be able to convert text input into numbers that correspond to the letters based on the following table where the left side is the input and the right is the converted output:

```
Group 1
A=11
B=12
C=13
D=14
E=15
F=16
G=17
H=18
I=19

Group 2
J=21
K=22
L=23
M=24
N=25
O=26
P=27
Q=28
R=29

Group 3 
S=31
T=32
U=33
V=34
W=35
X=36
Y=37
Z=38

Group 4
0=40
1=41
2=42
3=43
4=44
5=45
6=46
7=47
8=48
9=49

Group 5
"SPACE"= 50
"/" = 51
"," = 52
"-" = 53
```

The idea is there two numbers where the first number is a group: 1= a-i, 2=j-r, 3=s-z, 4=0-9, 5="space" "/" "," "-"
The second number represents the character within the group. hopefully, this all makes sense.

Now, what I need is something that can take text input, and convert it into these pairs of numbers.
The numbers need to be grouped in sets of three then printed to the page.

```
ex. 
user inputs text "hello world"
on submit the screen prints:
"181523"
"232650"
"352629"
"2314"
```

this would preferably be done completely using HTML. any help to point me in the right direction would be awesome!

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so we can help. Also, please read this: [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *"The idea is there two numbers where the first number is a group: 1= a-i,..."* - can you provide more examples of what this means? So far I see no correlation between the letter table, your explanation and the example.

Comment: I don't have any code yet as I have no idea where to start. I am by no means a website programmer, I only know this is possible, and hope someone can walk me through it.

Comment: @spectric, see the edited post above for a better explaination.

Comment: @Spectric That is how I want the result to be printed on the screen. The whole purpose of this is for use in a machine shop. the operators type in what they want to engrave into a part, say a serial #, this converts it into code the machine understands. Each set of six numbers will get entered into a variable on the machine. Tim.p4y and I got the full solution made, it is posted below

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example html page that will do what you're looking for. I don't have the result split up, and the code may not be super pretty, but it's functional  and I believe will do what you're looking for.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      const groups = {
        1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
        2: ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'],
        3: ['s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
        4: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
        5: [' ', '/', ',', '-'],
      }
      let resultVal = []
      const string = document.getElementById("inputString").value
      string.split("").map(val => {
        Object.entries(groups).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          if (value.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
            let group = key
            let alphPlace = value.indexOf(val) + 1
            resultVal.push(`${group}${alphPlace}`)
          }
        })
      })

      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultVal.join("");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input name="inputString" type="text" id="inputString" />
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <h1>Result:</h1>
  <p id="result"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution @tim.p4y came up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {

  var resTable = document.getElementById("resTableBody")
  resTable.innerHTML = ""
  const groups = {
                  1:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
                  2: ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'],
                  3: ['s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
                  4: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
                  5: [' ', '/', ',', '-'],
                  }
  let resultVal = []
  const string = document.getElementById("inputString").value
  string.toLowerCase().split("").map(val => {
    Object.entries(groups).forEach(([key,value]) => {
      if (value.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
        let group = key
        let alphPlace = value.indexOf(val)
        console.log(group, alphPlace)
        resultVal.push(`${group}${alphPlace}`)
      }
    })
  })
    let counter = 503
    
    resString = resultVal.join("")
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = resString;
    splitResults = resString.match(/.{1,6}/g)
    splitResults.map(val => {
      var res = document.createElement("tr")
      var th1 = document.createElement("td")
      var th2 = document.createElement("td")
      th1.innerHTML = "#" + (counter) + ":"
         counter = counter + 1
      th2.innerHTML = val
      res.appendChild(th1)
      res.appendChild(th2)
      resTable.appendChild(res)
    })
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input name="inputString" type="text" id="inputString"/>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Convert</button>
<h1>Results:</h1>
<table id="resTable">
  <tr>
     <th>Full String:</th>
     <th id= "result1"></th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="resTableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```